# Digital and Analog Power and Grounding

Tags: pcb, digital-logic, pcb-design, analog, grounding

I have been reading about grounding lately because I learned that this issue is very important for high frequency design and I got the idea that we have to think about the return current to avoid ground loops.

I am designing a board that should take into consideration this element.

So I am planning to have a single ground plane  and seperate the digital and analog tracks from each other so they don't interfere.

[image]

My first question :  Does the digital/analog power have to follow the same principal with analog/digital traces ? I mean do I have to place digital plane under digital traces and the same thing for analog ?

My 2nd question, will the power supply placement(/gnd) will make the analog return current carry some noise from the digital circuits in its way as show in the figure below ? or  do we consider just the ground plane and the return happening localy below the traces ?

My 3r question, I read that using multiple ground planes can tranform the PCB into a dipole antenna. Knowing that I need ground planes both under the top and bottom layer for the components I am placing . Should I limit the surface of these plane to the straigt minimum and place them only under the components instead of placing them on the whole layer ?

[image]

I hope this was clear. Let me know so I can clarify my questions more.

I really appreciate your opinions about this. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the high frequency in this design?

Comment: the highest is100 MHz

Comment: For 100MHz going across the PCB you're going to want a complete solid ground plane and power plane for the whole PCB, with as few discontinuities in them as you can manage.

Comment: Complete solid ground plane, yes. As for a power plane... it depends. Digital can be noisy, and may or may not produce harmonics in a band that affects the analogue section. The OP has also not specified whether there's a processor in the mix that has separated digital and analog Vdd inputs.

Comment: No the processor use only digital pins.